# using c++, How can I know whether a tensorflow tensor is in cuda or cpu?

Tags: tensorflow

i was writing a model inference engine based on tensorflow, is there anyway to know a TF Tensor on cuda device or cpu?

Answer (score 0):

just found can use `cudaPointerGetAttributes` to check if tensor is on CUDA or not, detail is attached. btw, following code is from: https://github.com/triton-inference-server/tensorflow_backend/blob/main/src/tensorflow_backend_tf.cc#L403

```cpp
void
TensorImpl::Init()
{
  nonstring_base_ = nullptr;
  nonstring_byte_size_ = 0;
  gpu_tensor_ = false;

  // Implement differently for string and non-string
  if (tftensor_.dtype() != tensorflow::DT_STRING) {
    auto flat = tftensor_.bit_casted_shaped<char, 1>(
        {tftensor_.NumElements() *
         tensorflow::DataTypeSize(tftensor_.dtype())});
    nonstring_base_ = static_cast<char*>(flat.data());
    nonstring_byte_size_ = flat.size();

    cudaPointerAttributes attributes;
    cudaError_t err = cudaPointerGetAttributes(&attributes, nonstring_base_);
    gpu_tensor_ =
        ((err == cudaSuccess) && (attributes.type == cudaMemoryTypeDevice));
  }
}
```